# react app displaying blank page after deployiment

Tags: reactjs, deployment

the issue i have with my react app is when i deployed my react app on server and typed my ip address/domain i would see a blank screen but if i refresh the page would briefly appear and disappear but if i add slash login i would be able to see the login screen and while it is on the homepage displaying blank screen and check in console i would see this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.map is not a function
at $i (Home.jsx:21:10)
at Ei (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
at Pf (react-dom.production.min.js:197:258)
at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:292:88)
at ks (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
at ys (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
at fs (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
at is (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
at x (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
```

but the code works very well on localhost

i even tried to add homepage"." to see if it works still did not work

Comment: We need more context. Show `Home.jsx`

Comment: "*i even tried to add homepage`"."`*" - what is that? If there where you deployed your app requires `homepage` then write your frontend link rather than `"."`.